# Prevent desktop.ini from being shared

Tags: file-sharing, windows-sbs, desktop.ini

I have a Windows server sharing a directory containing a large number of sub-directories.

Each sub-directory has a *desktop.ini* file which I cannot, for unrelated reasons, remove. (I know how to delete them, but a separate program which we must run on the machine will just recreate them if we remove them so they are, functionally, impossible to remove at the moment.)

Remote viewing of the share has become quite slow since the *desktop.ini* files appeared.

Since I cannot remove the files and would like to speed up remote viewing of the share, is there a way to prevent *en masse* the *desktop.ini* files from being announced to machines connecting to the share?

Alternatively, if the client machines can be configured to not scan and/or to disregard *desktop.ini* files, this may also solve the problem.

Comment: I don't know much at all about Windows servers, but I have this idea of making the machines that read files on the server be unable of seeing *desktop.ini* files by making them hidden files and not giving those "users" the permission to see hidden files. This might be totally silly, too.

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem. Are you **sure** that the desktop.ini files are making share access slow? Have you isolated it to this?

Comment: It's totally silly, @Ariane ;-) The _desktop.ini_ files are special system files that Windows will want to see regardless of whether or not they're hidden from the user. It must be told in some different way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is it, @allquixotic. The problem cropped up at the same time the files appear, doesn't show up for small sets of sub-directories, indexing is on, but, to close the case, you can use the `NET FILES` command to watch hundreds of access to _desktop.ini_s when someone opens this directory.

Comment: @Richard - If you delete the files, and disable the program that must be ran, do the problems return.  This is the only way to confirm if the desktop.ini and/or the program is the reason the problem exists.

Comment: @Ramhound, that is not the only way. The other way to confirm this would be to not share the files so that they cannot affect the time of the network load. This is the experiment I wish to perform - hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

The right question to ask is how to stop the machines from reading the `desktop.ini` files in the first place, and from generating the network traffic.  The wrong question to ask is how to make the server pretend that the files aren't there, which *won't stop the clients from making the requests for those files to the fileserver*.

Whenever a directory is marked with the read-only attribute, Explorer displays it according to what's specified in the `desktop.ini` file in that directory.  It sees the read-only attribute set, it goes and attempts to open and read a `desktop.ini` file.  The very simple answer here is to use [the `ATTRIB` command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc754186%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) or something similar to remove the read-only attribute from all of these folders.  Note that this will remove all folder customization from these folders.

Explorer doesn't let one change the read-only attribute using the properties dialogue.  You have to use some other program such as `ATTRIB` to do it.

#### Further reading

- Microsoft corporation (2011-06-28). [*You cannot view or change the Read-only or the System attributes of folders in Windows Server 2003, in Windows XP, in Windows Vista or in Windows 7*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326549).  ID 326549.  Microsoft KnowledgeBase.
- JP Software. [*ATTRIB*](http://jpsoft.com/help/attrib.htm).  Take Command / TCC Help.

Answer (score 0):

This works on windows 7.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"UseDesktopIniCache"=dword:00000000

Comment: Could you clarify how someone would locate this information? Please see [answer].

Comment: This is a new question. Make it so, and I will answer in it.

Comment: I'm trying to help you improve your answer to prevent it attracting low quality flags.

Comment: This is a "super user" forum, where people ought to know this FAQ. If you do not have the answer in a FAQ, then ask the question, I will answer it, and people can upvote enough to make it a FAQ.